# In Numpy, how do I find element wise inverse (reciprocal) of a given vector?

Tags: python, numpy

[image]

This shows my numpy session. I wish to find the reciprocals of the elements of a given vector and store it in another vector. The function power in numpy is not helping.

**Update**
This worked for me.

```
numpy.power(x*1.0,-1)
```

**Code sample**

```
import numpy
x = numpy.arange(5) + 1
print (x)
print (numpy.power(x, 2))
print (numpy.power(x, -1))
```

Comment: Please post your code samples as text not an embedded image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numpy provides a function to calculate [reciprocal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reciprocal.html) of the vector:

```
import numpy

x = numpy.arange(5) + 1
print (x)

r = numpy.reciprocal(x.astype(float))
print (r)
```

Which gives output:

```
[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]
[ 1.          0.5         0.33333333  0.25        0.2       ]
```

Note that your input method has to contain floats, otherwise output vector will be cast to integer and you will end up with: `[1 0 0 0 0]`.

Answer (score 3):

As stated by Maciej Lach, your input method has to contain floats (otherwise output will be cast to integers by the `numpy.reciprocal` method). But you can achieve it *even with integers* with:

```
1./x
```

(because `1.` is a float which will promote your results to floats).